# What do moderators do these days?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, election

More than 7 years ago, Scott Morrison asked a great meta question: [What do moderators do?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/931/what-do-moderators-do), and recorded some useful answers. Some seem to be of general significance, but many of the answers were specific to the period of migration.

In light of the current [moderator election](https://mathoverflow.net/election), I'd like to revive this as a new question: What do MathOverflow moderators do these days?

Here are some other current moderator-election-related meta questions:

**Currently active:**

[Questions for the candidates](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4947/2021-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)

**Of particular relevance to the current question:**

[Relationship between moderators and the board of MathOverflow, Inc.](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4940/would-newly-elected-moderators-join-the-board-of-mathoverflow-inc)

[Question about reason for election](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4960/reason-for-the-2021-moderator-election)

**Older ones:**

[Announcement](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4946/2021-community-moderator-election)

[Solicitation of questions for the candidates](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4915/2021-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

[Suggestions for nominees](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees)

Comment: This may be a good place to start: https://mathoverflow.net/help/site-moderators

Comment: Honestly, Tim, my impression is that *you* would make a very good MO moderator. Please consider this!